# Create a formula that takes the 4th symbol of a cell, If the 4th symbol is 8 the result from the formula needs to be 2018

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, helper

Please help me with the formula for this:

Create a formula that takes the 4th symbol of column A (Product_ID). If the 4th symbol is 8 the result from the formula needs to be 2018, if the symbol is 9 the result needs to be 2019

Product ID: IP1966712
IP1867546

I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you!!!

Comment: =IF(MID(A1, 4, 1) = "9", 2019, 2018)

Comment: Or even `=--(20&MID(A1,3,2))` or `=2000+MID(A1,3,2)`

Comment: @JvdV Can you explain what the "--" does?
=--"2019"

Comment: The double unary (also called a double negative) is an operation used to coerce TRUE FALSE values to ones and zeros, or (as in this case) turn text that looks like a number into a true numeric value @Prema.

Comment: @JvdV That double unary deserves to be in an answer - it is so useful.

Comment: @SolarMike, you can edit yours to include them if you want. No need for multiple answers here. (In fact, I voted to close the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the format of the number is always the same then to get the 4th character you can use:

```
=value(mid(A1,4,1))
```

Then you can use if():

```
=if(value(mid(A1,4,1))=8,2018,if(value(mid(A1,4,1))=9,2019))
```

You may need to trap errors.

Then, based on the answer provided by JvdV, you can also do this:

```
=IF(--MID(B10,4,1)=8,2018,IF(--MID(B10,4,1)=9,2019))
```

Where the double negative "--" deals with either True/False or numbers that are taken by excel as text as they are from text functions.