# Using excel formula to split long string into single cell list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for some help split a single string into a list within a single cell. What I am trying does not work correctly in Excel.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("x400",A1)-1),";",";"&CHAR(10))&MID(A1,SEARCH("x400",A1),LEN(Q95))
```

| Input | Wanted Output |
| --- | --- |
| smtp:ODonaDistributionGrouphidden@my.org.uk;X400:c=GB;a= ;p=MY;o=Exchange;s=ODonaDistributionGroup(hidden);;SMTP:ODonaDistributionGrouphidden@mycompany.com | ODonaDistributionGrouphidden@my.comp.uk; X400:c=GB;a= ;p=MY;o=Exchange;s=ODonaDistributionGroup(hidden); SMTP:ODonaDistributionGrouphidden@mycompany.com |

Comment: Have you considered MID() and define the start point and the number of characters? FIND() can also work here.

Comment: I'm not sure how to?

Comment: Weel, lots of examples on here. Have a look at mid() being used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891285/4961700

Comment: This isn't a programming question - just basic Excel usage. Maybe better suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)... (see [tour])  ...Nonetheless, `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"smtp:",""),"org","comp"),";;",";")` does the trick with the exception of 2 excess spaces in your desired output, which shouldn't affect whatever your connection string (or whatever)... or if you want it split by all semicolons, just use Text-to-Columns under the Data menu

Comment: @ashleedawg, that doesn't create a list, within a single cell?

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE()` has a 4th parameter where you can tell the function which occurence of the semi-colon you want substituted. It may come in handy if your input always follows the same pattern. In the shown sample it appears to be the 1st, 4th and 6th.

Comment: like this? ```    =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";SMTP",CHAR(10)&"SMTP"),";smtp",CHAR(10)&"smtp"),";X400",CHAR(10)&"X400"),";FAX",CHAR(10)&"FAX") ```